# Remove nan from annotations

Tags: python

How do I remove records with `y=nan` in a `list` of `dictionary` like below?

```
[{'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2018-Q3', 'y': 169.80000000000001, 'text': '169.8', 'showarrow': False}, {'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2018-Q4', 'y': 53.829999999999998, 'text': '53.83', 'showarrow': False}, {'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2019-Q1', 'y': 63.420000000000002, 'text': '63.42', 'showarrow': False}, {'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2019-Q2', 'y': 42.369999999999997, 'text': '42.37', 'showarrow': False}, {'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2019-Q3', 'y': nan, 'text': 'nan', 'showarrow': False}, {'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2019-Q4', 'y': nan, 'text': 'nan', 'showarrow': False}]
```

Comment: You have `nan` both as string and as actual nan. Is this how it is? or is it a mistake in copying it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1672063: The following solve your problem:

```
# let name your initial record "record"
# record = [{'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2018-Q3', 'y': 169.80000000000001, 'text': '169.8', 'showarrow': False},..]
#
# Let initialise a new record
newrecord = []
for d in record:
    if d['y'] is nan:   # provided that you "import numpy.nan as nan" at the beginning
       del d['y']
    newrecord.append(d)
```

# The "newrecord" corresponds the new record without d[y] = nan.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very well formed, but I'll make some assumptions and try to help.
Try this:

```
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan
dict_list = [{'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2018-Q3', 'y': 169.80000000000001, 'text': '169.8', 'showarrow': False}, {'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2018-Q4', 'y': 53.829999999999998, 'text': '53.83', 'showarrow': False}, {'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2019-Q1', 'y': 63.420000000000002, 'text': '63.42', 'showarrow': False}, {'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2019-Q2', 'y': 42.369999999999997, 'text': '42.37', 'showarrow': False}, {'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2019-Q3', 'y': nan, 'text': 'nan', 'showarrow': False}, {'yanchor': 'bottom', 'xanchor': 'auto', 'x': u'2019-Q4', 'y': nan, 'text': 'nan', 'showarrow': False}]
filtered_dict_list = [x for x in dict_list if not np.isnan(x['y'])]
```

It's a simple list comprehension filtering, google it...
Good luck!

---

Assumptions made:

- nan should be numpy.nan
- by "remove" you mean "get a new list of dictionaries which doesn't include the undesired dicts

Answer (score 0):

The below worked.

**newrecord2 = []
for d in annotations2:
    if d['text'] != 'nan':   # provided that you "import numpy.nan as nan" at the beginning
       newrecord2.append(d)
       #print newrecord**